# How can I prove that an infinite set is linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ denote the vector space of polynomials (of any degree) and $E_x : P \to \Bbb R$
denote the evaluation map $E_x(f) = f(x)$. Prove that the infinite set $\{ E_x : x \in \Bbb R \}$ is linearly
independent.

As I go about this I am aware of the theorem that states that if a subset of an infinite set is linearly independent, then the infinite set is as well. But how can I prove it in a way that shows that $\{E_x : x \in \Bbb R \}$ forms an orthogonal set with respect to an inner product?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You need to show that each finite subset of your infinite set is linearly independent.  You don't necessarily need an inner product to do that; you can work directly from the definition of linear independence.  Linear independence of the whole infinite set follows immediately from that.

Comment: Thank you. However, that is my question though. Despite proving it based on the definition of linear independence, is there a way I could prove it based on orthogonality?

Comment: In that case, you would have to construct an inner product with convenient properties. Perhaps possible, but there's no short cut as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $$F:=\sum_{k=1}^na_kE_{x_k}=0,$$ for some $n,$ points $x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_n$ and coefficients $a_k.$ Let $$P_j(x)=\prod_{k=1, k\neq j}^n(x-x_k).$$ Then $$F(P_j)=a_j\prod_{k=1, k\neq j}^n(x_j-x_k).$$ Hence $a_j=0$ for $1\le j\le n.$